# Can Formulas Automatically Update in Excel Services 2007?

Tags: excel-services

I currently have two spreadsheets housed in Excel Services in a Sharepoint Hub.  These two spreadsheets are linked.  However, the values on my main spreadsheet will only update 1. if the source document is opened or 2. if I click the Edit Links button and then click the Update Values button.  I tried clicking the Startup Prompt button in the Edit Links dialogue and selecting "Don't display the alert and update links", but that didn't work.   Is there any programming that can be added to the main spreadsheet to force it to update values without needing to click on the Edit Links button and then click on Update Values?  If I have these same two documents housed on my computer, the links update when the main document is open.  Is there a way to get the spreadsheets to act this way in SharePoint?

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.